# c++ binary search tree program program running but result not showing

Tags: c++

i am new in programing in c++ 
in my program i am entering data in program using binary search tree 
when i compile the program there is no error 
but result not showing 
process is ended with this statement

process exited with return value 32212225477

press any key to continue...

my code is here

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<iostream> 
using namespace std;  
struct node 
{ 
    int key,empSalary;
    string empName;
    struct node *left, *right; 
}; 


struct node *newNode(int item,string name, int salary) 
{ 
    struct node *temp =  (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node)); 
    temp->key = item;
    temp->empName = name;
    temp->empSalary = salary; 
    temp->left = temp->right = NULL; 
    return temp; 
} 


void inorder(struct node *root) 
{ 
    if (root != NULL) 
    { 
    inorder(root->left); 
    cout<<root->key<<"\t"<<root->empName<<"\t"<<root->empSalary;
    inorder(root->right); 
    } 
} 

struct node* insert(struct node* node, int key,string name, int salary) 
{ 
    if (node == NULL) return newNode(key,name,salary); 

    if (key < node->key) 
        node->left  = insert(node->left, key,name,salary); 
    else if (key > node->key) 
        node->right = insert(node->right, key,name,salary);    

    return node; 
} 

int main() 
{ 

    struct node *root = NULL; 

    root = insert(root, 32,"Raza",3000); 
    insert(root, 56,"Sajjad",25000); 
    insert(root, 93,"Rabia",19230); 
    insert(root, 5,"Sehar",24000); 
    insert(root, 10,"Ali",22200); 
    inorder(root); 

    return -1; 
}
```

please help me about this 
i think there is an runtime error 
i also have set return 0;
but in same.
thanks in advance

Comment: Typically when you see a crazy result code like 32212225477, convert it to hex and see if it is more recognizable. In this case it isn't. 7 7FFF 8DC5 doesn't match any error code I've ever seen.

Comment: On an unrelated note, don't return `-1` from the `main` function. The usual is to return `0` if there's no error (and which is the default if you don't have an explicit `return`), or a small positive number (less than 256) if there's an error.

Comment: I guess that's -1 casted to unsigned as in the code above, main() return -1

Comment: @DDMC -1 is typically a whole mess of FFs courtesy of good ol' two's compliment. While it's possible, I can't think of any encoding that's likely to turn -1 into 7 7FFF 8DC5. That would be on hell of a weird computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One major problem is that you use `malloc` for your memory allocations. That will only allocate memory, but not call the constructors.

This means your `string` member `empName` will not be constructed and that leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) when you attempt to use it (and the crash you seem to have).

If you need to dynamically allocate memory in C++ you should always use `new` (and pair it with `delete`).

And a general hint: If you ever need to use C-style casting (like you do with the returned value from `malloc`), then that's a sign that you're probably doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following things with your code.

1. Replaced malloc with new
   Standard way to allocate memory in C++
2. Removed using namespace std
3. Made node struct uppercase to distinguish it from other types
4. Using C++ nullptr for all Null pointers
5. Introduced an empty root node, that is always there an never removed

   - Helps with the border cases
6. Returning EXIT_SUCCESS instead of -1
7. Removing struct in front of node type, as not necessary
8. node can be const in inorder, as there is no intention to change anything
9. I used an initializer list to fill Node with data

**Revised code**

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>

// Use Capital letters for classes improves readability
struct Node
{
    int key{0};
    int empSalary{0};
    std::string empName;
    Node *left{nullptr}; // Initialize with default values, avoids undefined behaviour
    Node *right{nullptr};
};


// You can write simply Node* instead of struct Node
Node *newNode(int item, std::string name, int salary)
{
    // Initializer list and new
    return new Node{ item,salary,name};
}


void inorder(const Node *root) // Node is const, so make it so
{
    if (!root) return;
    inorder(root->left);
    std::cout << root->key << "\t" << root->empName << "\t" << root->empSalary << "\n";
    inorder(root->right);
}

Node* insert(Node* node, int key, std::string name, int salary)
{
    if (!node) return newNode(key, name, salary);

    if (key < node->key) {
        node->left = insert(node->left, key, name, salary);
    } else if (key > node->key) {
        node->right = insert(node->right, key, name, salary);
    }

    return node;
}

int main()
{
    Node *root = newNode(0, "ROOT", 0); // Is always there and avoids taking special care about empty trees, especially when deleting nodes

    root=insert(root, 32, "Raza", 3000);
    insert(root, 56, "Sajjad", 25000);
    insert(root, 93, "Rabia", 19230);
    insert(root, 5, "Sehar", 24000);
    insert(root, 10, "Ali", 22200);
    inorder(root->right);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: What changes did you make? Why did you make them? Why is your code better than the one the OP shows?

Comment: Recommendations: Highlight and explain what you changed. Other than a few tangential bits of useful information at the beginning, this is a code-only answer, and code only answers have an annoying tendency to produce [Cargo Cult Programmers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming)

Comment: @user4581301: Many thanks for the hint. Maybe I should remove my answer.

Comment: @Aleph0 no, you shouldn't necessarily delete the answer, but rather apply what the comments suggest.

Comment: i am new and according to your code i am in trouble there are many other errors that i don't know how to remove if i remove malloc then result is same as with malloc. i think problem is in newNode code..
can any body explan..

Comment: @NadeemIjaz: What kind of errors did you got with my code. Can you please post your code and your errors. Did you compile with a C++ compiler?